# How to install (compile) Imagemagick php module with parallel php setup

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have two PHP installations in parallel. When i am compiling the imagick module for php, it is including the wrong directory.

After:

```
    /usr/local/php-5.3.21/bin/phpize
```

configure goes for the wrong php:

```
    checking for PHP prefix... /usr
    checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main
```

which i need to be: /usr/local/php-5.3.21/include/php

I tried ./configure with --prefix, --includedir, --oldincludedir ... but it did not change the include

Once two lines in the Makefile are changed, the module compiles correctly:

```
    -phpincludedir = /usr/include/php
    +phpincludedir = /usr/local/php-5.3.21/include/php
    -INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main ...
    +INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/php-5.3.21/include/php ...
```

If just i would understand a bit more about this autoconf stuff. I have basically no idea where to change the behaviour of configure to correct the path settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `./configure` script is finding the first `php-config` in your environment's PATH variable, and extracting PHP location information to populate the makefile. To force a specific installed version of PHP, use the `--with-php-config` option.

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php-5.3.21/bin/php-config
```

Comment: Thanks. If i'll find the time, i'll fumble that into the phpize code.